# What is this table of jmp instructions to functions that I always see in disassembly of MSVC output?

Tags: assembly, visual-c++, x86, linker

```
00007FF755AF1118  jmp         __scrt_get_dyn_tls_init_callback (07FF755AF2730h)  
__scrt_dllmain_crt_thread_attach:
00007FF755AF111D  jmp         __scrt_dllmain_crt_thread_attach (07FF755AF1E90h)  
__acrt_thread_attach:
00007FF755AF1122  jmp         __scrt_stub_for_acrt_thread_attach (07FF755AF4F30h)  
__acrt_thread_detach:
00007FF755AF1127  jmp         __scrt_stub_for_acrt_thread_detach (07FF755AF4F40h)  
__crt_fast_decode_pointer<void (__cdecl** __ptr64)(void)>:
00007FF755AF112C  jmp         __crt_fast_decode_pointer<void (__cdecl**)(void)> (07FF755AF1B20h)  
__report_rangecheckfailure:
00007FF755AF1131  jmp         __report_rangecheckfailure (07FF755AF49A0h)  
__scrt_initialize_default_local_stdio_options:
00007FF755AF1136  jmp         __scrt_initialize_default_local_stdio_options (07FF755AF26A0h)  
__scrt_exe_initialize_mta:
00007FF755AF113B  jmp         __scrt_stub_for_initialize_mta (07FF755AF2B00h)  
f:
00007FF755AF1140  jmp         f (07FF755AF1490h)  
__scrt_get_dyn_tls_dtor_callback:
00007FF755AF1145  jmp         __scrt_get_dyn_tls_dtor_callback (07FF755AF2740h)  
__scrt_acquire_startup_lock:
00007FF755AF114A  jmp         __scrt_acquire_startup_lock (07FF755AF1DA0h)  
ReadNoFence64:
00007FF755AF114F  jmp         ReadNoFence64 (07FF755AF2C70h)  
_guard_icall_checks_enforced:
00007FF755AF1154  jmp         _guard_icall_checks_enforced (07FF755AF2CC0h)  
ReadPointerNoFence:
00007FF755AF1159  jmp         ReadPointerNoFence (07FF755AF2CA0h)  
__acrt_thread_attach:
00007FF755AF115E  jmp         __scrt_stub_for_acrt_thread_attach (07FF755AF4F30h)  
__scrt_exe_initialize_mta:
00007FF755AF1163  jmp         __scrt_stub_for_initialize_mta (07FF755AF2B00h)  
__scrt_unhandled_exception_filter:
00007FF755AF1168  jmp         __scrt_unhandled_exception_filter (07FF755AF2B10h)  
... etc etc this table is huge.
```

My theory is it's to help the linker for things like edit and continue because then the linker can dump the new function anywhere in the memory space and then just patch this jump table to the new location. But I don't have edit and continue enabled right now and I still see this sometimes when a fair amount of optimizations are turned on.

1. What is it called? I want to know what to google for.
2. Why does it exist?
3. Extra credit: Can I query its existence somehow through the [Windows Debug API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/debug/debugging-functions)?

Comment: All of these functions are defined in the C runtime initialization library. Other than that, it's difficult to fully answer the question without precisely describing how we can reproduce that table.

Comment: I see a jump table for debug builds, but not for release builds. It's not clear to me how having a jump table helps with debug builds.

Comment: Oh I didn't take a close enough look at the actual function names when I first commented. If this is in debug builds it is because it was built with incremental linking on. One method used by incremental linking is for functions calls to be done indirectly through this table. If you modify a function a new version is added to the end of the executable and the pointer for it is modified in the jmp table to redirect to the new version of the function. If you build a release version or disable incremental linking this doesn't apply.

Comment: So if I had read your entire post closely at the bottom I would have realized you were on the right track. My apologies.

Comment: @rcgldr : Incremental linking uses it for patching

Comment: If this table is what I believe it should also have a bunch of 0xcc bytes for future thunk entries when new functions are added. And if this is what I think it is now, this question can be closed off as a duplicate because there are similar questions on SO.

Comment: According to the Microsoft docs release builds may have this turned on.There is a warning to ensure they are turned off in release builds: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/incremental-link-incrementally?view=vs-2017 .

Comment: @MichaelPetch - true, but the default for release builds is incremental link off.

Comment: @rcgldr : That has been my experience which lead me to the original statement "If you build a release version or disable incremental linking this doesn't apply". I'm only suggesting that Microsoft is warning that a user should ensure the setting is off. Makes me wonder if there are cases with some versions of MSVC/VS where that might not be the case. I just found the warning that was highlighted to be interesting because my personal observations lead me to believe that it was off by default.

Comment: @MichaelPetch - I never got the community version, so I never got VS 2017. I do have VS2005 (retail), VS2008 (express), VS2010 (express - last one that can run on Win XP), and VS2015 (desktop express). Default for release build for those versions is incremental linking off.